# Find equation of circle with given pair of intersecting lines

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Question:
A line $L_1$ defined by $y =m_1x+c_1$ intersects the circle $S$ defined by $x^2+y^2+2Fx+2Gy+C$ at $P$ and $Q$. The line is then rotated about a point $(a,b)$ lying on $L_1$ to form $L_2$, defined by $y=m_2x+c_2$,
which intersects $S(x,y)$ at $R$ and $S$. If the combined equations of lines $PR$ and $QS$ is $ax^2+by^2+2hxy+2gx+2fy+c$, find the equation of the circle.

Note: Everything except $F$, $G$, and $C$ is given. I only want to learn how to approach this problem. It will be especially helpful if you could generalize it.

Comment: Hint: Convert the equations of the lines in $(a,b,c)$ form, where the line is $ax+by+c=0$. Then the equation of the two lines is $(a_1 x+b_1 y + c_1)(a_2 x+b_2 y + c_2)=0$. Also make sure the expression for the circle _is an equation_ because I think you are missing the `=0` above.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ in the point $(a,b)$ the same as those in the equation of linear pair $ax^2+by^2+2hxy+2gx+2fy+c=0$?

Comment: You should pick a different symbol for either the circle or one of the intersection points of the second line with that circle. You have $S$ representing both.

Comment: If, as you say, _everything_ aside from the equation of the circle is given, then you can construct it from any three of the four intersection points with the circle. The equations of the lines and their combined equation are distractions.